# Помогите с qt creator

Tags: qt, creator

Ребят, помогите отключить желтые предупреждения в qt creator, вроде банальная вещь но в гугле не нашел как, очень калит видеть их в таком количестве. Заранее большое спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В главном меню QtCreator: Help -> About plugins, снимите галку с пункта Clang Code Model и перезапустите Creator.

При желании можно будет запустить анализ вручную в главном меню Analyze -> Clang-tidy and clazy